# Finding IDs that are consistently over average

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a customer df that looks like this:

```
id  |date  |value
 1  |180101|47749
 1  |180401|12390
 ......
 120|200101|479874
```

For 120 customers it has a row for every quarter.

I have another df that has the average value per date across all the customers:

```
date  |value
180101|57293
180401|18487
 ......
200101|673737
```

I want to find the customers who are consistently above average for their value for all the dates. I want to filter the customer dataframe to find customers for every date has a value above average.

I tried but it was throwing an error and I don't think its what I want :

```
top = df_customer[df_customer['value'] > means['value]]
print(top['cust_id'].nunique())
```

Comment: post your attempt of solving this.

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi please see my attempt. Not really sure whats the best way to approach it

Comment: @dsexplorer, What error message were you getting?  Maybe you need to convert your value to integers, otherwise it seems reasonable

Comment: Does `means` dataframe have `id`? Consider joining both dataframes on columns `id` and `date` then create your boolean mask.

Comment: @MrSoLoDoLo The means data frame does not have `id`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df_customer.merge(means, on = 'date', how = 'left', suffixes = ('_actual', '_mean'))
top = df_customer[df_customer['value_actual'] > df_customer['value_mean']]
```